# How to gain ownership of external HDD (and all files/folders) mounted to /mnt

Tags: debian, permissions

I've plugged in a USB Hard Drive to my new Debian Jessie machine.  I've got it to auto-mount by updating /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=21AE-9B96 /mnt/local/ext001 vfat defaults 0 2
```

...but it's owner is root and won't let me change anything.  I've mounted it as /mnt/local/ext001 and have tried to:

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 ext001
```

...it grants me ownership over ext001, but nothing in it or below it, giving me:

```
Changing ownership of xyz, : Operation not permitted
```

I've attempted this using sudo and su.  Where am I going wrong?﻿

Comment: Try to adapt the permissions of the directory `ext001` accordingly _before_ mounting the VFAT volume.

Comment: The fat32 filesystem doesn't keep track of file or directory ownership, but try adding `uid=1000,gid=1000` to the mount options to make the files and directories appear to be that uid/gid.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @EliasProbst No, that wouldn't help. This directory exists solely to be a directory entry which can be used as a mount point; its metadata is ignored.

Comment: @Gilles OK. I'd like to wait for OP to confirm it solves the problem.